# have a responsive modal in a rails app

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, crop, jcrop

I have a app where I am providing crop functionality. So on click of upload I am opening a modal like below.

```
<div id="uploadfile" class="modal"  tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"> 

                <div class="modal-dialog modal-med" style="width:auto">

            <div class="modal-content modal_extra  modal_reorder modal_font" style="background-color:#59D0CA;width:auto;position:relative;height:auto;display:inline-block; width:77%">     

            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
              <h6 style="color:black"> Oh, that's a nice image!
         </h6>
           Select area you want to use
    <div class="modal-body-step5" style="padding:17px;">           
< div id="cropimages"  >
</div>
</div>
 </div>
 </div>
  </div>
```

After this, I am opening the image on the left hand side of the modal. and providing a previewbox for the same on the right hand side of the image, making sure the gaps between them are proper.

Now the trouble I am facing is, when I upload images with different width/height, It is not looking proper. It is overlapping the present buttons or the previewbox.

How can I fix this?

Its a rails app, so Its very difficult for me to create a fiddle for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Without any illustration, I'll have to give a broad answer.

--

Modal forms (which are typically positioned *absolute*) are quite difficult to make "responsive" as `absolute` elements are [out of the standard DOM flow](http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-positioning-19970819#Positioned):

> (W3C) For that matter, the layout of each 'absolute' positioned element is independent of any others.

This means that to keep the form working properly, you have to assign a specific `width` and `height` to it (IE `50px` etc). Relative proportions don't lend themselves to absolutely positioned elements, although it is possible.

This is your main problem - how to get your image to show proportionally to an element which is very difficult to make relative.

--

The simple answer is to use a dynamically-sized image inside a container (where `width` or `height` is a percentage of the container, the resolve `overflow:hidden`):

```css
.two-hundred {
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    background: #ff0;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

.container {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
}
.container img { 
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container two-hundred">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" />
</div>
```

[image]

--

There is a [good example you can use here](http://bvc-video.herokuapp.com) (you'll have to sign up and go to profile in the top right hand corner):

[image]

--

This should work for a modal (IE setting an image container, embedding the image and keeping it at 100% width / height).

*However*, the problem arises when you deal with `responsive` design. If you want to make a modal *responsive* (IE changes proportions depending on screen size), your container will have to assume a `%` width:

We struggled with this for some time, but found a [relatively simple solution](http://red-team-design.com/horizontal-centering-using-css-fit-content-value/):

```
.modal {
    position: fixed;
    top: 10%;
    left: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    width: intrinsic;
    width: -moz-fit-content;
    width: -webkit-fit-content;
    max-width: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

This is extremely close to a truly responsive modal. It fills the modal based on the content (IE dynamic width), and maximizes that width at `50%`.

This means you can limit the max width to achieve a responsive interface.

You'd be able to use the code structure above (IE `.container img`) to place an image inside the modal, which you can then define relatively.